# Image carousel slow to load once hosted

Tags: javascript, html, css, hosting

I built a pretty simple website for a friend that is essentially an online brochure for a property listing and experiencing a bug. The site was built using just basic HTML/CSS/JS.

The bug is once I hosted the site, the image carousel is extremely slow to load only on Apple products and takes me reloading the page once after initially visiting the page to fix the lag. On Android and windows products it works fine.. Here is the link to visit to see what I mean:

http://armanicondoforsale.com/

Also for reference is my code here:

https://github.com/JenniferJGomez/Armani

Wondering if this is a performance issue or perhaps a bug only Apple products experience?

Comment: Maybe load lower res images on apple devices?

Comment: I'm thinking I might have to as it seems that  this is a performance issue. There's also definitely something in my JS code that Firefox browsers don't like.